# Two objective functions

Tags: prolog, eclipse-clp

If we have two objective functions in Eclipse CLP that `Cost1` is more important than `Cost2`, is the following true?

```
minimize(minimize(labeling(Vars), Cost1), Costs2).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this works, provided you tell the inner minimize to compute all optimal solutions, rather than just the first one (use the [bb_min/3](https://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/branch_and_bound/bb_min-3.html) variant of `minimize`):

```
:- lib(ic).
:- lib(branch_and_bound).

minmin(X, Y) :-
    [X,Y] #:: 1..4,
    Cost1 #= -2*X,
    Cost2 #= -Y,
    bb_min(
        bb_min(
            labeling([X,Y]),
            Cost1,
            bb_options{solutions:all}
        ),
        Cost2,
        bb_options{solutions:one}
    ).
```

The operational behaviour is that first `Cost1` is minimized (ignoring `Cost2`), then `Cost2` is minimized (with `Cost1` fixed at its minimum):

```
?- minmin(X, Y).
Found a solution with cost -2
Found a solution with cost -4
Found a solution with cost -6
Found a solution with cost -8
Found a solution with cost -1
Found a solution with cost -2
Found a solution with cost -3
Found a solution with cost -4
X = 4
Y = 4
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```